# Unable to force Eclipse to use the Project instead of the jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, maven-plugin

I'm facing a problem with Eclipse and Maven.
I have 2 Maven projects in my Eclipse's workspace :

- Project A : uses Maven but is not declared as Maven project in Eclipse
- Project B : declared as Maven project in Eclipse and has a dependency with Project A

=> Project B has the jar of Project A in the "Maven Dependencies" of Maven plugin for Eclipse.

My problem is that when I build Project B in Eclipse, it uses the jar of Project A (which is in M2_REPO) instead of the Eclipse project directly, although I have the property "**Resolve dependencies from workspace projects**" enabled in the Maven plugin settings.

Does anyone have an idea for my problem ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: One might think of a third project, containing both as modules, sub-projects.

Comment: Is there any reason not to declare projectA as maven for eclipse??

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't create a third project.  
Project A is not declared as Maven project because it is an old project which is not only used by my Project B